# Delphi 7 Debugger Freezes in 64-Bit environments

Tags: debugging, delphi-7, windows-server-2012

I have replicated this problem on Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2, and Windows Server 2016.  Do a clean install of Delphi 7.  Create a new project with a single form.  On the form's OnCreate event add this code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  list: TStringList;
begin
  list:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    Form1.Caption := list[0];
  except
    on E:Exception do begin
      Form1.Caption := E.Message;
    end;
  end;
  list.Free;
end;
```

When you run the program you will get a blank form with the window title "List index out of bounds (0)".  Not too interesting.

Now put a break point on the first line of this procedure, open the Watch List and add the following watches:

```
list.Count
list.Text
```

Run the program.  Everything is still fine.  Both variables say "Expression is illegal in evaluator" or an "Access Violation at BLAH accessing BLAH" until the list is creted, and then list.Count=0 and list.Text="".  Now add the following watch:

```
list[0]
```

In Delphi 7 on a Windows Server 2003, once the list is created you will get a value for list[0]="Delphi exception EStringListError at $BLAH".  Still what you'd expect.  On any of the 64-Bit systems before the list is created all is well. 
 Once the list is created, however, the value for list[0] is either "[Evaluating...]" or "[process not accessible]".  The debugger is frozen.  You can not add/delete watches.  You can not single step or run the program.  You have to reset the program.  Even after resetting the program the Watch List is still frozen.  You have to restart Delphi to return things to normal behavior.

I have tried running Delphi 7 in every conceivable compatibility mode AND running the program as an administrator.  All result in the exact same behavior.

The best I can tell, this happens when indexing off the end of any kind of list.

Any ideas as to why I'm seeing this behavior?  Any suggestions on how I might fix (other than don't ever add a watch that indexes off the end of a list)?

Comment: Why are you accessing out of bounds? Why don't you just stop that.

Comment: I should. That's why I like using a debugger.

Comment: I was just trying to demonstrate how to crash the debugger crashes, and this the simplest example of how to show it.  I don't think a debugger should crash if you have a watch variable that is out of bounds.

Comment: You're using an IDE that is a decade and a half old that was developed for ancient Windows 95 and expecting it to work flawlessly on a modern 64-bit OS. It won't. Downgrade your OS or upgrade your Delphi version.

Comment: @Ken MS compatibility is pretty good. I have no troubles running the even older Delphi 6 on modern windows.

Comment: Can you recommend the best version of Delphi since 7 for creating native apps?  I have tried several versions and were never impressed enough with any of them to upgrade.  I also think the quality of the IDE has gone backwards. With their focus on multiple platform apps, the quality of the native apps generated has also degraded. As an example, a self contained app with a blank form in Delphi 7 creates a small exe that loads instantly. I did the same with one of the later versions of XE and the app was about 10 times the size and took seconds to load.

Comment: Shannon, the upgrade would be to the current version of Delphi, which (in most SKUs) includes licenses back to Delphi 2007. We have production applications that are being maintained in D2007 both developed and running on Windows 7 and 10 64-bit OSes, and we haven't experienced any difficulties.

Comment: Ken, so are you recommending Delphi 2007 (before Embarcadero came on the scene) or Delphi 10.2?

Comment: "I have tried running Delphi 7 in every conceivable compatibility mode". The debugger is a stand alone program. Maybe you need to set the compatibility mode for it explicitly.

Comment: If you live in EU, you can find cheap second hand Delphi licenses. In EU you are allowed to sell/buy second hand products (a license is still a product). Any version beyond 2009 is good. I find XE to be as stable as Delphi 7. Or find a friend in EU to buy a license on his name and then to gift it to you.